# Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'T[keyof T]'

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, generics, javascript-objects

I am trying to write a function with generic types which takes two args (array of obj and search term) but I am getting an error - **Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'T[keyof T]'**

here is the function:

```
function matchSearchTerm<T>(data: T[], search: string): T[] {
  return data.filter((obj) => {
    const filteredData = (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof typeof obj>).some((value) => {
      return (
        typeof obj[value] === "string" && obj[value].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      );
    });
    return filteredData;
  });
}
```

What is missing here?

Comment: Your array is of generic type `T` and the function `toLowerCase()` is not defined on that type, hence the error message. You need to cast the array item to `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems related to this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530

You can still pull the `obj[value]` out into a variable to get the type inference:

```
function matchSearchTerm<T>(data: T[], search: string): T[] {
  return data.filter((obj) => {
    const filteredData = (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof typeof obj>).some((value) => {
      const val = obj[value];
      return (
        typeof val === "string" && val.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      );
    });
    return filteredData;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function matchSearchTerm<T extends Record<string, string>>(data: T[], search: string) {
  return data.filter((obj) => {
    const filteredData = (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>).some((value) => {
      const checkIt = obj[value]
      return (
        typeof obj[value] === "string" && obj[value].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      );
    });
    return filteredData;
  });
}
```

Just add extra constraint to your `T` generic parameter:`T extends Record<string, string>`

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
return obj[value]['toLowerCase']?.call(obj[value]).includes(search.toLowerCase())
```

in my eyes its returning true/false/undefined -> for filters its fine... or we can use some ternary operator, if we want just true/false....