# Why can't typescript infer the type of `T[key of T]` for type parameter `T` here?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a generic class that is passed a key `key` corresponding to a key of one of a set of known interfaces on construction and that can later be passed an object `thing` and type-safely access `thing[key]`. This is what I've got:

```
interface AB {
  a: string
  b: number
}

interface BC {
  b: number
  c: Date
}

type ABC = AB | BC

class Getter<T extends ABC> {
  key: keyof T;

  constructor(key: keyof T) {
    this.key = key;
  }

  get(thing: T): string {
    const value = thing[this.key];
    return value.toString();
  }
  
}

const getter = new Getter<AB>('b');
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIICFkG8BQzlwBcyAzmFKAOZ7IBGxIArgLa3Q4C+OOoksiKdAGFsNesiat2+BMQAicSJ25gAngAcUGEQF40mAD7Jh3BABs4JEsgDiEMHwA8AFWQQAHpBAATa9oA0yADSEKpunhA+1gDWoQD2MMjOAHyi+LGqxCGqANzcMnEgZFCMCGBxUAAUGVmhAJRp+MhgABbAJAB0Gch6GXn4XDSU9pWtVMTOdcTFVI34UPaMUCDNbSCUANpjnRkAuh3lAMrkVJV1-chc+JxAA)

Here, I'd expect Typescript to infer that because `T extends ABC` that `T[keyof T]` = `AB[keyof AB] | BC [keyof BC]` = `string | number | date`. However, it seems to get stuck at `T[keyof T]`. Even adding an `as AB[keyof AB] | BC[keyof BC]` to that line doesn't fix it, I need `as unknown as AB[keyof AB] | BC[keyof BC]`! Is there any way to get this working without that line?

Also, is there any way I could parameterize over the value of `key` as a type instead of parameterizing over the type of `thing`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'T\[keyof T\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67901487/property-tolowercase-does-not-exist-on-type-tkeyof-t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `T extends ABC`, it can have many other properties and types. Which can therefore not have `.toString()` method.

```
type G = {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  hello: undefined;
};

const g = new Getter<G, keyof G>("hello");

g.get({
  a: "a",
  b: 1,
  hello: undefined
}); // undefined does not have .toString() method
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIICFkG8BQzlwBcyAzmFKAOZ7IBGxIArgLa3Q4C+OOoksiKdAGFsNesiat2+BMQAicSJ25gAngAcUGEQF40mAD7Jh3BABs4JEsgDiEMHwA8AFWQQAHpBAATa9oA0yADSEKpunhA+1gDWoQD2MMjOAHyi+LGqxCGqANzcMnEgZFCMCGBxUAAUGVmhAJRp+MhgABbAJAB0Gch6GXn4XDSU9pWtVMTOdcTFVI34UPaMUCDNbSCUANpjnRkAuh3lAMrkVJV1-chc+Mo4apq2PY1EpCfrF+KSbFAXLRBmZnFiIwfBAYKAIN48lwEIUyMhKI8QBAAO62exOGyBDIJWzJSoAIl+-zi+Lq3EoHWGYEquHwz3xcHx-jExAAjMz8ESAUCQWCkd5OOduMDvKDwd4DnFjhR1mc8kA)

Comment: oh huh! is there any way to achieve what I was going for typesafely then? Is there any way to restrict T to be either AB or BC? Or maybe just that all of its values need to implement the interface `{ toString: () => string}`?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I could parameterize over the value of key as a type instead of parameterizing over the type of thing?

Yes, nothing easier than that:

```
class Getter<Key extends string | symbol> {
  key: Key;

  constructor(key: Key) {
    this.key = key;
  }

  get(thing: {[k in Key]: string | number | Date}): string {
    const value = thing[this.key];
    return value.toString();
  }
}
```

<sup>([Playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiCmAXR8BOAeA0vAnteAHigHYAmMEiqAlsQObQA+0EOAtgEYD2IAfNAG8AUNGgBrXAC5o2HAG4hI6MC7FKqAK7BEXVAAoJOabICUgpaMQALahAB0h6AF5xuBaIC+i0XSR7rtHTSAgDaYtC0MrgAutLqgUzQxBqcaIkAImAoHiZxVAnCoqIqaojQAG5gIBrwztAB9CEB9obR7kWoSBqoxBVVNXY6AMr59Hom7V5eQiWU0L7IaS7E8ADucEgo+gDkHNsTQgtbdgt6AhzS2yiU2zly0AD0D9CrumIQh5toJ37n0skgEB3R7PFRsAAO4FoMD0kHwBHB8G08FIJiAA))</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a limitation of the nature of typescript.
You need to check members, then do a typed cast at runtime.
Hope that helps!

For example:

```
if (AnimalObject.Object.Keys().Includes('Name')) {
  // We now know the generic type has a matching member
}
```

As for an implementation, I was would make a list of interfaces that 'T' can be then make an array of members for each interface, following the above logic you may end up with something like:

```
// Store your valid types for checking
const ValidInterfacesSet: any[] = {Dog,Cat,car,Mammal};

//Look through members and confirm them... 
GetAndCastType(typeToCheck: any) {
    typeToCheckKeys: string = typeToCheck.Object.keys();
    for (inter: any of ValidInterfacesSet) {
        const interMemberNames: string[] = inter.object.keys();
        
        if(array1.sort().join(',')=== array2.sort().join(',')) {
          // Returning the casted type if the iter members contain the same as typeToCheckMembers
             return typeToCheck as inter; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by check members and do a typed cast?

Comment: For example if you have an interface 'Animals' and it contains members 'Name' and 'Type'.
You can generically confirm these members and then execute a case to the animal interface.
if (AnimalObject.Object.Keys().includes('Name')) {
  
(I'll add more details in the answer for you)