# Is there any way to implement my class in a type-safe manner?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In Typescript, I have two interfaces `A` and `B`, both of them having the method `.toString()` on all of their values. I want to write a class `Getter` that can take a property name `key` on construction, and then later be passed an object `thing` conforming to one of these interfaces, and return `thing[key].toString()`. I want to do this type-safely, so that if `key` does not exist on `thing`, I get an error.

(Note that each `Getter` will only ever be passed objects of a single interface, known at compile time.)

I can't figure out how to do this: I tried having the type parameter `extend A | B` where `A` and `B` are the two interfaces this class needs to be used on, but [that runs into issues, as we could define an interface `C` that extends `A` but does not have `.toString()`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72568655/19285680) I then tried having it `extend Record<string, Stringable>` (where `Stringable` is an interface consisting only of `{ toString: () => string }`) but this doesn't work because [`Record` implies it's acting as a dictionary, which it isn't.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37006179/19285680) I've also tried parameterizing it over a `Field` type that `extends string`, but I'm not sure if this would work given that I wouldn't know the value of `Field` at compile time.

Is this actually possible to do in typescript? If not, are there any alternative methods to what I'm trying to achieve?

(Note also that this is a toy example; in my actual code the class needs to perform an expensive computation on construction and then will be passed tons of objects in a loop, which is why its structured this way.)

## Code Example

### What I'm trying to do

```
interface Stringable {
  toString: () => string
}

interface A {
  a: number
}

interface B {
  b: Date
}

class Getter<AB extends /* some type here */> {
  key: keyof AB;

  constructor(key: keyof AB) {
    this.key = key;
  }

  get(thing: AB) {
    return thing[this.key].toString();
  }
}

const bGetter = new Getter<B>('b');
bGetter.get({b: new Date(0,0)});
// "Mon Jan 01 1900 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)" 

const aGetter = new Getter<A>('b');
// type error

bGetter.get({a: 105});
// type error
```

### First Failure

Changing `/* some type here */` to `A | B` doesn't work because if `AB extends A | B` then `{a: number, c: undefined}` satisfies `AB`.

### Second Failure

Changing `/* some type here */` in the above to `Record<string, Stringable>` doesn't work because neither `A` nor `B` are compatible with that type.

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] that demonstrates what you're doing in addition to your verbal description?  Something concrete that can be dropped into an IDE would help others get started.

Comment: @jcalz I do have a reproducible example of my first failure in the first link and the second failure contains its own code example, but I'll add an example of my ideal interface for this.

Comment: Links to other questions do not count as a [mre]; they are nice supplements, but all the code necessary to demonstrate an issue should be present as plain text in the question itself.  Example code should be self-contained, so that nobody *needs* to navigate away from the question to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can just do:

```
class Getter<AB extends Record<keyof AB, Stringable>>
```

Not in a position to test, so let me know if it works or not.

Comment: This would be my suggestion also

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize you could reference AB in its own definition!